# shell script with interesting bug

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, debugging

I've found such behavior of bash `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and even latest ( How to get version of dash? ) dash on Debian.

Bug as is:

```
/bin/echo "Silent Err 'unexpected EOF while looking for matching' Example:"

if [ 0 -eq 1 ]; then
        /bin/echo "HERE IS MISTAKE WITHOUT QUOTE IN THE END
        exit
fi

/bin/echo " BLACK HOLE "
/bin/echo " CODE WILL NEVER PROCEED "

if [ 0 -eq 1 ]; then
        /bin/echo "SECOND MISTAKE
        exit
fi
/bin/echo "normal code... will work";
/bin/echo "Good and silent exit without any notice about BLACK HOLE code..."
/bin/echo "exit."
```

**Launching:**

```
# bash bug_as_is.sh 
Silent Err 'unexpected EOF while looking for matching' Example:
normal code... will work
Good and silent exit without any notice about BLACK HOLE code place...
exit.
```

Only if the first `if then fi` block  will be quoted, than error appears:

```
# bash unbug.sh 
Silent Err 'unexpected EOF while looking for matching' Example:
 BLACK HOLE 
 CODE WILL NEVER PROCEED 
unbug.sh: line 20: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
unbug.sh: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is it common known bug or I've found real diamond? (;

And what is backbone of this behavior?

Comment: The fact that `BLACK HOLE` etc is printed is not a bug, what makes you think it is? Hint: look at the syntax highlighting in your editor, or even in your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no bug in bash: the code is working just as it should.

bash allows multi-line strings as arguments to `echo` even if those strings look odd and contain what would otherwise be bash code.

Note that the following is simply one `echo` statement with a multiline string for output:

```
        /bin/echo "HERE IS MISTAKE WITHOUT QUOTE IN THE END
        exit
fi

/bin/echo " BLACK HOLE "
/bin/echo " CODE WILL NEVER PROCEED "

if [ 0 -eq 1 ]; then
        /bin/echo "SECOND MISTAKE
```

To clarify, let's replace that long string with `"multiline string omitted"`.  Then, the code is simply:

```
/bin/echo "Silent Err 'unexpected EOF while looking for matching' Example:"

if [ 0 -eq 1 ]; then
        /bin/echo "multiline string omitted"
        exit
fi
/bin/echo "normal code... will work";
/bin/echo "Good and silent exit without any notice about BLACK HOLE code..."
/bin/echo "exit."
```

The above is properly working code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "backbone of this behavior" means, but as I interpret it:

The (seemingly) unmatched quoted string `"HERE IS MISTAKE WITHOUT QUOTE IN THE END` actually just starts a quoted string literal. That string literal goes past the first `fi` and encompasses everything up to the double quote character that begins `"SECOND MISTAKE`.

So, `bash` can parse the whole mess, albeit improperly from a human standpoint. It does turn out, since 1 does not numerically equate to 0, that the entire block of code, from `/bin/echo "HERE IS MISTAKE` to the `fi` following `"SECOND MISTAKE` does not get executed. So  the (apparent) string `SECOND MISTAKE` is parsed correctly, as a possible command, but `bash` never tries to execute it, so we don't see an error about `SECOND: command not found` or whatever.

Just to summarize, the missing quotes on two lines cause `bash` to parse the code as the "true" clause of a single `if-then-fi`, but the condition is false, so `bash` never tries to execute what the human eye sees as a bad command, and doesn't give a relevant syntax error.